# How do i add nested arrays to UITableView with SwiftyJSON

Tags: json, swift3, alamofire, swifty-json

I'm venturing into the world of programming and have run into som head-scratching with JSON. I'm using Swift 3, SwiftyJSON and Alamofire

Here's the JSON data I'm looking at:

```
{
"status": "OK",
"latlng": [55.7182304595, 12.4136193718],
"northingseastings": [6180000, 714400],
"results": [{
    "frequencyAreas": [
        [470, 485],
        [495, 517],
        [527, 541],
        [559, 565],
        [575, 581],
        [591, 613],
        [623, 645],
        [655, 709],
        [719, 725],
        [743, 773],
        [783, 790]
    ],
    "guardBand": 1,
    "lastChannel": 60,
    "tvChannelsNoGuardBand": [
        [21, 22],
        [24, 26],
        [28, 29],
        [32, 32],
        [34, 34],
        [36, 38],
        [40, 42],
        [44, 50],
        [52, 52],
        [55, 58],
        [60, 60]
    ]
 }]
}
```

What I need to do is to add everything whithin `"frequencyAreas"` to a `UITableView`.

I'm able to get all frequencies just fine using the following inside `viewDidLoad`:

```
let url = "https://frekvens.erhvervsstyrelsen.dk/findKanalerAPI.php?output=JSON&language=da&northings=6180000&eastings=714400"

            Alamofire.request(url, method: .get).validate().responseJSON { response in

            switch response.result {

            case .success(let value):
                let json = JSON(value)

                if let _ = json["results"].array {

                    for result in json["results"].arrayValue {

                        let frequencies: Array<JSON> = result["frequencyAreas"].arrayValue

                        print(frequencies)

                    }

                } else {

                    print("json error: \(String(describing: json.error))")
                }


            case .failure(let error):
                print(error)
            }
        }
```

However I have absolutely no idea how I can add the data in `frequencyAreas` into my `UITableView`.

Here's what i get when I call `print(frequencies)`:

```
[[
  470,
  485
], [
  495,
  517
], [
  527,
  541
], [
  559,
  565
], [
  575,
  581
], [
  591,
  613
], [
  623,
  645
], [
  655,
  709
], [
  719,
  725
], [
  743,
  773
], [
  783,
  790
]]
```

What i would like to see happen, is that the nested arrays are added to a UITableView like so:
cell 1: 470, 485
cell 2: 495, 517
cell 3: 527, 541
cell 4: 559, 565
etc.

Here's what i have so far. This only returns the first element (i.e 470) and adds that to a cell.

```
internal func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return frequencyList.count

}


internal func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as? frequencyTableViewCell

    for (index, value) in frequencyList.enumerated() {


        frequencyList[index] = value
        let bands = frequencyList[index]
        print(frequencyList)
        cell?.title.text = String(describing: bands[index][indexPath.row])

        }

    return cell!
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by  **I have absolutely no idea how I can add the data in frequencyAreas into my own array variable.**? because you are already having frequencyAreas array

Comment: I don't know how to extract the values inside `"frequencyAreas"` (e.g 470, 485 etc.) and append those values to an array of my own.

Comment: From your json response it is look like that 470 and 485 related to each other also  495, 517 and so on.. Are you sure that you want to make Single dimensional array from 2d array

Comment: What those values describe are areas in the frequency band where wireless michrophones are not permitted to operate, so I need to display those two values to the user. 470, 485 just tells the user that they are not allowed to adjust the frequency of their wireless michrophone in that specific range.

Comment: Then why you want to convert it to Single Array can you show your desired ouput

Comment: I'm sorry. The mistake is mine here. Please excuse me, since I'm very new in this field. You are correct, I don't want it to be a single array, since I want to display each value to the user in separate cells in a `UITableView`. So how do I go about that?